# can't recover a failed gluster node

Tags: linux, glusterfs

I created a glusterfs (6.1) cluster with 6 servers (node01 - node06) in Replicate (=6) mode but cannot recover a failed server (node01, this vm was reset/rebuilt but I want to keep its hostname/ip) following this tutorial (https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/recover-from-a-failed-server-in-a-glusterfs-array/):

- I can add node01 back to the cluster by getting UUID from a running server (gluster peer status) and updating "/var/lib/glusterd/glusterd.info" file (node01)
- I then updated extended attributes (trusted.glusterfs.volume-id) of node01 directory and restarted gluster service:

> sudo setfattr -n trusted.glusterfs.volume-id -v *hash* /data/brick1/vol
>
> sudo systemctl restart glusterd
>
> sudo gluster volume heal vol full
>
> sudo gluster volume heal vol info

- logs and outputs:

> sudo gluster volume status

```
Brick node01:/data/brick1/volr              N/A       N/A        N       N/A
Brick node02:/data/brick1/volr              49152     0          Y       5734
Brick node03:/data/brick1/volr              49152     0          Y       5733
Brick node04:/data/brick1/volr              49152     0          Y       5691  
Brick node05:/data/brick1/volr              49152     0          Y       5721  
Brick node06:/data/brick1/volr              49152     0          Y       5723
```

> sudo gluster volume heal vol full

```
Launching heal operation to perform full self heal on volume volr has been successful
Use heal info commands to check status.
```

> sudo gluster volume heal vol info

```
Brick node01:/data/brick1/volr
Status: Transport endpoint is not connected
Number of entries: -

Brick node02:/data/brick1/volr
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0

Brick node03:/data/brick1/volr
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0

Brick node04:/data/brick1/volr
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0

Brick node05:/data/brick1/volr
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0

Brick node06:/data/brick1/volr
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see in the log files at `/var/log/glusterfs/`, especially `/var/log/glusterfs/glusterd.log`?  You have a good chance of finding the cause in that log file.

Comment: Nothing special,no error messages (E) found in glusterd.log. but in glustershd.log, I can see something like "0-vol-client-0: intentional socket shutdown(11)"

Comment: Is `glusterd` actually running on `node01`?  You can check with `sudo systemctl status glusterd.service`.  If it's not running or encountered some kind of error, maybe the cause is logged in `sudo journalctl -xe --unit glusterd.service`.

Comment: yes, it is running: sudo systemctl status glusterd, active: active (running). No error found in logs so far.

Comment: Is `node01` peered with the other nodes?  Check with `sudo gluster peer status` on `node01` and any of the other nodes.

Comment: sudo gluster peer status
Number of Peers: 5

Hostname: node02
Uuid: xxx
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)

Hostname: node04
Uuid: xxx
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)

Hostname: node03
Uuid: xxx
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)

Hostname: node05
Uuid: xxx
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)

Hostname: node06
Uuid: xxx
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)

Comment: I was able to reproduce your exact situation on my own GlusterFS nodes.  Once I fix the problem, I'll write an answer to document how I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply and help. Have a nice day~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with the exact same symptoms.

You correctly peered the reinstalled node, `node01`, but the brick replacement procedure isn't well-documented.

The [official documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190423085612/https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Managing%20Volumes/#replace-brick) has some weird instructions for changing out the faulty brick for a new one with a different name.  It's unnecessarily complicated, and I think you want to use the same brick name.

You weren't able to get the brick running because the replacement brick didn't have necessary metadata stored in `node1:/data/brick1/volr/.glusterfs`.

Here's what I did to replace the brick:

---

Assuming that:

- `node01` is the rebuilt server that has already been peered,
- there is a volume called `vol`, and
- the brick to be replaced is `node01:/data/brick1/volr`

Do the following:

1. On `node01`, shut down GlusterFS:

   ```
   sudo killall -9 glusterd glusterfsd glusterfs
   ```
2. Remove the brick to have a clean slate:

   ```
   sudo rm -rfv /data/brick1/volr
   ```
3. Create the brick folder again:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -pv /data/brick1/volr
   ```
4. Restart `glusterd.service`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart glusterd.service
   ```
5. Reset the brick:

   ```
   sudo gluster volume reset-brick vol node01:/data/brick1/volr node01:/data/brick1/volr commit
   ```
6. If the healing process has not started already, start it:

   ```
   sudo gluster volume heal vol full
   ```

---

## Additional Resources

- [Reconfiguring a Brick in a Volume](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.2/html/administration_guide/sect-migrating_volumes#sect-Migrating_Volumes-Reconfigure_Brick) from the Red Hat Customer Portal Product Documentation
- (*Paywall*) [How to replace a failed glusterfs brick from new brick having same name as old brick in same glusterfs node ?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1291663) on the Red Hat Customer Portal Knowledgebase

Comment: Haven't tried above cmds but just wondering does it work on a replica=3 cluster (we have to make sure brick count should be a multiple of the replica count) or even with a distributed dispersed cluster?

Comment: @BrianX: I have updated my answer with a better procedure that _should_ work for all types of volumes.  (I've only tested the instructions on a `replica 3` volume.)

Comment: cool, it does work on my current setup. Will also try it out on a distributed 
 dispersed cluster later. Many thanks!

Comment: @BrianX: Great!  Please check the gray check box next to the answer to indicate that it was helpful.

Comment: Sure. Already did it.

Comment: Accepted the answer but I don't have much reputation to vote.